# How to ignore a property declared as Object based on the value's actual type when serializing with a custom ContractResolver

Tags: json.net, ravendb

I have a class like this:

```
class Test
{
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes, `Obj` has the value of a non-serializable type, such as: `byte[]` or `SqlDataReader`.

I tried to make a custom `ContractResolver` to ignore the property when value type is `byte[]`. But it is not working: the property type is still `Object`, not `byte[]`.

```
public class AutoIgnoreComplexTypesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private static readonly List<Type> IgnoredTypes = new List<Type>()
    {
        typeof(byte[]),
        typeof(SqlDataReader)
    };

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var propertyType = property.PropertyType.GetUnderlyingType();

        if (IgnoredTypes.Contains(propertyType))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;
        }
        else
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => true;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Can you help me to get the real value type and ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`property.PropertyType` will return the declared (compile-time) type of the property, which is always `object` here.  If you want to base the decision to serialize on the actual runtime type of the property's value, you'll need to get the value from the `instance` using reflection and then check its type.
Try it like this instead:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(object))
    {
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance =>
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = member as PropertyInfo;
            object propertyValue = (pi != null) ? pi.GetValue(instance) : null;
            return propertyValue != null && !IgnoredTypes.Contains(propertyValue.GetType());
        };
    }
    else if (IgnoredTypes.Contains(property.PropertyType))
    {
        property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;
    }

    return property;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2A2KMH